# Combine several video files into a stream with Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, video-streaming

Trying to create something like a online TV channel that streams random videos from the Internet.

I am OK to download and uncompress the videos. But how do I create a stream out of them?

I read that I can split the videos in chunks and give them to the client one by one. Is this the only approach?

What js libraries, should I use?